# Desplazar <div> interactuando con otro <div>

Tags: html, css

Tengo un div y en su interior contiene una imagen. Bajo este div hay un texto que solo se verá cuando desplace el div. Esto quiero que ocurra cuando pulse la imagen del div superior. En ese momento el contenedor se desplazará y dejará ver el texto que hay en la capa inferior.

De momento he utilizado la pseudoclase **:focus** para marcar la imagen al hacer click en ella, de manera que esta añade sombra y modifica el tamaño, pero ahora no se como hacer para que el div contenedor se desplace en la misma acción hacia un lado y deje ver la capa inferior.

```css
.seccion{
    display: flex;
    position: relative;
    margin-top: 80px;
    justify-content:center;
}
.contactos{
    position: relative;
    height: 100%;
    width: 50%;
    align-items: center;
    z-index: -100; 
}
.contactos div{
    padding: 30px;
    z-index: -100; 
}
.contactos2{
    background-color: transparent;
    position: absolute;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 100;
}
.contactos3{
    background-color: #000000;
    padding: 10px 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 33%;
    text-align: center;
}
#git{
    width: 80px;
    height: 80px;
    border-radius: 10px;
}
#git:hover{
    box-shadow: 0 8px 8px 0 rgba(255, 215, 0, 0.5);
}
#git:focus{
    width: 120px;
    height: 120px;
    transition: 1s;
}
#mail{
    width: 80px;
    height: 80px;
    border-radius: 10px;

}
#mail:hover{
    box-shadow: 0 8px 8px 0 rgba(255, 215, 0, 0.5);
}
#mail:focus{
    width: 120px;
    height: 120px;
    transition: 1s;
    
}
#link{
    width: 80px;
    height: 80px;
    border-radius: 10px;
}
#link:hover{
    box-shadow: 0 8px 8px 0 rgba(255, 215, 0, 0.5);
}
#link:focus{
    width: 120px;
    height: 120px;
    transition: 1s;
}
```

```html
<section class="seccion">
        <div class="contactos2">
            <div class="contactos3" id="gitdiv"><img id="git" tabindex="0" src="imagenes/git.png"/></div>
            <div class="contactos3" id="maildiv"><img id="mail"  tabindex="0"  src="imagenes/gmail.png"/></div>
            <div class="contactos3" id="linkdiv"><img id="link"  tabindex="0"  src="imagenes/linkdin.png"/></div>
        </div> 
        <div class="contactos">
            <div>
                <img src="imagenes/neon.png"/> 
            </div>
            <div>
                <img src="imagenes/matemaki.png"/>
            </div>
            <div>
                <img src="imagenes/linkedin.png"/>
            </div>
        </div> 
    </section>
```

Answer (score 1):

Puedes hacer con **traslate** de css, ese efecto lo puedes asignar a la etiqueta **img** de html, con el efecto al hacer **":focus" o click**  la animacion seria así:

```css
.seccion {
  display: flex;
  position: relative;
  margin-top: 80px;
  justify-content: center;
}

.contactos {
  position: relative;
  height: 100%;
  width: 50%;
  align-items: center;
  z-index: -100;
}

.contactos div {
  padding: 30px;
  z-index: -100;
}

.contactos2 {
  background-color: transparent;
  position: absolute;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 100;
}

.contactos3 {
  background-color: #000000;
  padding: 10px 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 33%;
  text-align: center;
}

#git {
  width: 80px;
  height: 80px;
  border-radius: 10px;
}

#git:hover {
  box-shadow: 0 8px 8px 0 rgba(255, 215, 0, 0.5);
}

#git:focus {
  width: 120px;
  height: 120px;
  transition: 1s;
}

#mail {
  width: 80px;
  height: 80px;
  border-radius: 10px;
}

#mail:hover {
  box-shadow: 0 8px 8px 0 rgba(255, 215, 0, 0.5);
}

#mail:focus {
  width: 120px;
  height: 120px;
  transition: 1s;
}

#link {
  width: 80px;
  height: 80px;
  border-radius: 10px;
}

#link:hover {
  box-shadow: 0 8px 8px 0 rgba(255, 215, 0, 0.5);
}

#link:focus {
  width: 120px;
  height: 120px;
  transition: 1s;
}


/*Aqui le damos la animacion a la etiqueta img*/

img {
  height: 50px;
  background-color: rgb(11, 35, 30);
  width: 25%;
  transition: 2000ms all cubic-bezier(0.19, 1, 0.22, 1);
  transform: translateX(-22%);
  left: 30px;
}


/*img al hacer focus*/

img:focus {
  transform: translateX(60%);
  left: 0px;
}
```

```html
<section class="seccion">
  <div class="contactos2">
    <div class="contactos3" id="gitdiv"><img id="git" tabindex="0" src="imagenes/git.png" /></div>
    <div class="contactos3" id="maildiv"><img id="mail" tabindex="0" src="imagenes/gmail.png" /></div>
    <div class="contactos3" id="linkdiv"><img id="link" tabindex="0" src="imagenes/linkdin.png" /></div>
  </div>
  <div class="contactos">
    <div>
      <img src="imagenes/neon.png" />
    </div>
    <div>
      <img src="imagenes/matemaki.png" />
    </div>
    <div>
      <img src="imagenes/linkedin.png" />
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Y también puede ser al hacer **:hover**:

```css
.seccion{
    display: flex;
    position: relative;
    margin-top: 80px;
    justify-content:center;
}
.contactos{
    position: relative;
    height: 100%;
    width: 50%;
    align-items: center;
    z-index: -100; 
}
.contactos div{
    padding: 30px;
    z-index: -100; 
}
.contactos2{
    background-color: transparent;
    position: absolute;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 100;
}
.contactos3{
    background-color: #000000;
    padding: 10px 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 33%;
    text-align: center;
}
#git{
    width: 80px;
    height: 80px;
    border-radius: 10px;
}
#git:hover{
    box-shadow: 0 8px 8px 0 rgba(255, 215, 0, 0.5);
}
#git:focus{
    width: 120px;
    height: 120px;
    transition: 1s;
}
#mail{
    width: 80px;
    height: 80px;
    border-radius: 10px;

}
#mail:hover{
    box-shadow: 0 8px 8px 0 rgba(255, 215, 0, 0.5);
}
#mail:focus{
    width: 120px;
    height: 120px;
    transition: 1s;
    
}
#link{
    width: 80px;
    height: 80px;
    border-radius: 10px;
}
#link:hover{
    box-shadow: 0 8px 8px 0 rgba(255, 215, 0, 0.5);
}
#link:focus{
    width: 120px;
    height: 120px;
    transition: 1s;
}

/*Aqui le damos la animacion a la etiqueta img*/
img {
  height: 50px;
  background-color: rgb(11, 35, 30);
  width: 25%;
  transition: 2000ms all cubic-bezier(0.19, 1, 0.22, 1);
  transform: translateX(-22%);
  left: 30px;
    }


/*img al hacer hover*/
img:hover{
  transform: translateX(50%);
  left: 0px;
}
```

```html
<section class="seccion">
  <div class="contactos2">
    <div class="contactos3" id="gitdiv"><img id="git" tabindex="0" src="imagenes/git.png" /></div>
    <div class="contactos3" id="maildiv"><img id="mail" tabindex="0" src="imagenes/gmail.png" /></div>
    <div class="contactos3" id="linkdiv"><img id="link" tabindex="0" src="imagenes/linkdin.png" /></div>
  </div>
  <div class="contactos">
    <div>
      <img src="imagenes/neon.png" />
    </div>
    <div>
      <img src="imagenes/matemaki.png" />
    </div>
    <div>
      <img src="imagenes/linkedin.png" />
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: Está bien si lo que busco es mover la img. Realmente lo que necesito no es desplazar la img en si. Busco que, al hacer click sobre la imagen, el contenedor completo se mueva. Tal vez esto es con JS, que pulsando un elemento dentro de un contenedor se desplace el contenedor completo.

Comment: Agrega el **traslate** al _div_ y no al _img_, con eso funciona, y claro, también lo puedes hacer con **Javascript**, pero seria lo mismo, debes crear una función que modifique los _estilos css_.